# Absolute Database file to sqlite converter

Tags: delphi, sqlite

I have some db file which are generated with Absolute Database Delphi component [1]. Is it possible, through programming or a tool, to convert it into something open like sqlite?

Thanks,

1. http://www.componentace.com/bde_replacement_database_delphi_absolute_database.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you follow your link, the features page indicates that it comes with a DBImportExport utility;

Utilities
DBImportExport utility to transfer your existing tables from database systems with BDE driver, such as Paradox, Interbase, Access, Oracle, SQL Server to Absolute Database format and vice versa.
Absolute Database Manager to manage a database easily and to perform all supported operations with tables and database file
With Absolute Database Manager you could also easily execute SQL queries
All utilities come with full source code and can be used as an advanced examples

It also states that it's free for personal use.